# How did the Green Snake defeat Fahai?

Tags: white-snake

At the beginning of *The Green Snake*, Xiao Qing and Xiao Bai confront the monk [Fahai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahai). When they first fight him, he effortlessly wards off the massive wave they summon to swamp his temple, breaks Xiao Bai's magical hairpin, and casts Xiao Qing into Asuraville.

However, by the end, after Xiao Qing fights Fahai countless times in his realm between Asuraville and the mortal world, she finally is able to defeat him, without her sister's help, no less. Of course, with practice, her magical skills might have improved, but then, so too might those of Fahai. Not to mention, a few decades of practice surely are not much in comparison to the hundreds or thousands of years of experience that she had up until that point.

How did Xiao Qing become powerful enough beat Fahai?

Comment: Is this relating to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Snake_(film)? And is this directly related to the animated *White Snake* film, or more toward [the original legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_White_Snake)?

Comment: And is that the same *Green Snake* as on Netflix?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - The animated film, and yes, "The Green Snake" is a sequel.